# How to update multiple div's while using Ajax.Begin form and how to show server side errors on modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to create a page(CRUD operations) in asp .net mvc using Bootstrap modal. I have studied some articles and found partial views are best for this approach. I have done most of the functionalities but stuck in some issues. Please check and guide.

Here is my main Index view. This is partial view which will be used in other page. This view displays data inserted into db and have Div which renders partial views for add and edit operations:

```
<div class="grading" id="tblUserEducation">
    <div class="persn-detl sp-0">
        <p>
            <h3>Education</h3>
            <a href="javascript:void()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userEducationModal">Add Education</a>
        </p>
        @foreach (var item in Model.userEducationVm)
        {

            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.School) </h5>
                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Degree), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fieldofstudy), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)</div>
                @if (item.Activities != null)
                {
                    <p>
                        Activities: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Activities)
                    </p>
                }
                <p>From Year: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FromYear) To Year @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ToYear)</p>
                @if (item.Description != null)
                {
                    <p>
                        Description:<br />
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </p>
                }
                <div class="add-editing">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void()" onclick="editUserEducation(@item.Id)"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

</div>




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="userEducationModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button id="btnCloseEducationModal" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Education</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="divUserEducation" style="height:500px;overflow-x:auto !important;">
                @{Html.RenderAction("Create", "UserEducation"); }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My Create Partial view (Removed some HTML):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "UserEducation", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divUserEducation" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="School" class="form-control-label">School:</label>

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.School, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.School, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Degree" class="form-control-label">Degree:</label>

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Degree, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Degree, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>



    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
}
```

This is my Index and Create Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new UserEducationViewModel
    {
        userEducationVm = userEducationService.getUserEducationAllRecords(),
        YearsInDropDown = clsCommonMethods.getYearsForDropDown()
    };
    return PartialView("_UserEducationIndex", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserEducationViewModel vObj)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserEducation obj = new UserEducation();
            obj.School = vObj.School;
            obj.Degree = vObj.Degree;
            obj.Fieldofstudy = vObj.Fieldofstudy;
            obj.Grade = vObj.Grade;
            obj.Activities = vObj.Activities;
            obj.FromYear = vObj.FromYear;
            obj.ToYear = vObj.ToYear;
            obj.Description = vObj.Description;
            obj.Description = vObj.Description;
            userEducationService.insertUserEducation(obj);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            vObj.YearsInDropDown = clsCommonMethods.getYearsForDropDown();
            return PartialView("~/Areas/MemberArea/Views/UserEducation/_UserEducationCreate.cshtml", vObj);
        }
    }
    catch
    { return RedirectToAction("Index"); }
}
```

Here is some Issues I am facing:

1. I have created custom validation which only works server side. So when Model.State is not valid I want to show create popup with server error. For this I have set my UpdateTargetId property to "divUserEducation"(Where Partial Create view renders). This shows error messages but when there is no error message and data is submitted to server, it shows Index view in popup.

I want to update Index view when data successfully saved and wants to show create form with error message when there is any validation error.

If I change UpdateTargetId to "tblUserEducation" it updates new entries on index page but when there is validation error it does not shows create page inside popup.

Here is my ViewModel Class:

```
  public class UserEducationViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string School { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Degree { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Field of Study")]
    public string Fieldofstudy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Grade { get; set; }

    public string Activities { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "From Year")]
    public Nullable<int> FromYear { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "To Year")]
    public Nullable<int> ToYear { get; set; }


    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public List<UserEducation> userEducationVm { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> YearsInDropDown { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ToYear < FromYear)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("To Year cannot be smaller than From year.", new[] { nameof(ToYear) });
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You have two `return RedirectToAction(..)` line of code in your `Create()1` method which is pointless since ajax calls never redirect - all your doing is return the html generated by the `Index()` method.

Comment: Get rid of `Ajax.BeginForm()` and use `$.ajax()` which will give you far more flexibility. Your method could return json indicating success or other wise, and if not, include a collection or errors - e.g. `return Json({ success = false, errors = yourCollection });` and then in the success callback, if successful, dynamically add a new `<div class="col-xs-12">` and its child elements based on the values in the modal form (there is no need to degrade performance by sending back the whole collection when you have all the information you need in the client), and if not, then render the errors.

Comment: ok, I think $.ajax() is the last option. Still looking for any solution with Ajax.BeginForm() to prevent my work. If you have any example using $.ajax() please share.

Comment: Why would you want to use effectively obsolete methods (the MVC team is not supporting it in the latest versions). Using the jquery ajax methods will give you far better performance as well since your not returning a whole lot of unnecessary html that already exists in the page. How are you generating `ModelState` errors - are they associated with specific properties - e.g. `ModelState.AddModelError("someProperty", "someError");` or are they `ModelState.AddModelError("", "someError");`?

Comment: I have custom validators like this:
 public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (ToYear < FromYear)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("To Year cannot be smaller than From year.", new[] { nameof(ToYear) });
            }


        }
I am just checking this as if (ModelState.IsValid)

Comment: So they are property specific. Which means that you should be rendering the error `ToYear` in its `@ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ToYear)` :) And you can easily write your own validation attribute so that you get client side validation for that - refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) or simply use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` or similar attribute. Having said that, you still need the server side check.

Comment: Give me an hour or so and I will add an answer using `$.ajax()` methods, but please add the example validator code to your question so my answer makes sense

Comment: @StephenMuecke Viewmodel class added. Thanks for your help. Yes I want some validations to be checked on server side.

Comment: Note I have added an answer with the outline code, but have run out of time. I will complete the script (for displaying the errors or the new html in 2 - 3 hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Ajax.BeginForm()` with `Html.BeginForm()` and use the jquery `ajax()` methods to submit your form, and have the method return a `JsonResult` of your errors if there are any. You can then update the DOM with the errors if there are any, or if successfully, just add the html for your new element based on the values that are already in your form controls (the only extra data that needs to be returned by the method is the new ID of the object you created.

Your form will be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "UserEducation"))
{
    .... // form controls etc as above
}
```

and the script to handle the submit

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "UserEducation")';
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the default submit
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
        return; // exit if there are client side errors
    }
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post(url, formData, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            var id = response.id;
            // Build html for new item based on the values in the form
            // See notes below
            $('#userEducationModal').hide(); // Close the modal form
        } else {
            $.each(response.errors, function(index, item) {
                // Find the corresponding element generated by ValidationMessageFor()
                var placeholder = $('span[data-valmsg-for="' + item.propertyName + '"]');
                var message = $('<span></span>').text(item.errorMessage);
                placeholder.addClass('field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-valid').append(message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And your controller method will be

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(UserEducationViewModel vObj)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });
        return Json( new { success = false, errors = errors });
    }
    try
    {
        // Map the view model to the data model, save and return the new ID
        return Json( new { success = true, id = obj.Id })
    }
    catch
    {
        // Not sure what you want to do here, but returning a friendly error message seems appropriate
    }
}
```

To add the html, the easiest method would be to add a 'template' in a hidden div element, for example

```
<div id="template" style="display:none">
    <!-- Repeat the same html that is in your foreach loop without the object values, but add class names so elements can be easily selected -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h5 class="school"></h5>
        <div class="degree"></div>
        ....
</div>
```

and that will be even easier is you create a custom `DisplayTemplate` for your object that including those class names, and then you can replace your `foreach` loop with

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.userEducationVm)
```

which will generate the correct html for each item in the collection, and then add

```
<div id="template" style="display:none">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NewUser)</div>
```

where property `NewUser` is a default instance of `UserEducationViewModel` in your view model. The code to add the new html then becomes

```
var clone = $('#template').clone();
// update the values based on the form controls
clone.find('.school').text($('#School').val());
...
// Append it to the DOM
tblUserEducation.append(clone.html);
```

Comment: Thanks @stephen I have tried solution provided by you. two points not working:
1) How to show error message on appropriate position.
2) How to update my Index after data saved?

Comment: Thanks a lot @stephen, I am waiting.

Comment: Have updated the answer. Note I cannot test the code at the moment, and I cannot remember if the linq query returns `vObj.ToYear` for the `propertyName` or just `ToYear`. I have assumed the latter, so it that bit is not working, the prefix needs to be removed - just let me know if that's the case.

Comment: As a side note refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) for a simple example of adding/editng items based on a modal form and a template

Comment: Thanks I am not in office now I'll try tomorrow. How to update index view after save or update?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephen It solves my all problems. To update my Index I have simply create partial view and render inside: if (response.success) {